# Rename file and lock issue for P4V

Tags: locking, p4v

When I use P4V to add one file(mark for add), then I rename the file, so now the file is locked and can not be submitted or deleted. The tip info is "The system cannot find the file specified.". So what am I gonna to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your change list, revert your changes to file.bad, add as the new name.